# how to change id tag in table rows

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to change the td.firstChild on each row using jQuery?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="wrong" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="wrong" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="wrong" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="wrong" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

to this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="1" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="2" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried with this several ways but it seems that it doesn't do it for each row. It just adds the row count to all of them. I have also managed to increment it for each td.firstChild in the table.

```
var i = 0;
var rows = $("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        $("td").each(function () {
            this.firstChild.setAttribute("name", i);
        });
    }
```

or

```
$("tr").each(function (i) {

        $("td").each(function () {
                this.firstChild.setAttribute("name", i);
            });
    });
```

is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Id attribute should be unique

Comment: sorry, I realized that it should be the Name instead. But the procedure should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("tr").each(function (index, value) {

    $("td", value).each(function (index2, value2) {
            $("input", this).prop("id", "NewID" + index + index2);
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8n3Z/

Here, you are getting the td in the context of the row, then applying the new ID to the input inside of that using jQuery's prop method.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never have duplicated id on your page.

As for this question, you just need to travel child `td` in the `tr`, not looping all the `td` tags again and again.

```
$("tr").each(function (i) {
        $(this).child("td").each(function () {
                this.firstChild.setAttribute("id", i);
        });
});
```